# Refresh regular view and embedded view

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript, lotus-formula

I have a view from which I can open documents and change its status. After I change status document is being closed but view doesn't refresh until I press F5. Same thing happens when I create a response document from an document with embedded view. Embedded view should show all repsonce documents and its status.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After changing document call

```
Dim workspace As New NotesUIWorkspace
Call workspace.ViewRefresh
```

in your Lotus Script code or

```
@Command( [ViewRefreshFields] )
```

in your formula.

Comment: Hi Knut, first of all thank you for your immediate response. But my question is where do I place the code? For example when I open the document from the view (not embedded) in View's event? or in document itself?

Comment: You'd  place code where you create document (button) or in form event if you open it in UI and save it manually.

Comment: Hi Anatoly, a good place for code lines is QueryClose event in form in your case.

Comment: Knut, I've tried put your code there but it didn't work, instead I placed it in buttons which make changes and then save and close document. Not it works. Thank you very much for your help.